# No Internet After Uninstalling Avira Internet Security

Tags: windows, internet, anti-virus, uninstall

I am having an issue with one of client machine where after uninstalling Avira Internet Security I lost my internet connection.

A weird thing is that, I can still open one website, but not the rest.

Troubleshooting I did so far:

1. Command prompt:

   `netsh winsock reset`

   `netsh interface ipv4 reset`

   `netsh interface ipv6 reset`

   `ipconfig /flushdns`

   `Restart Computer`.
2. Reinstalled NIC.
3. System Restore.
4. Checked with other browsers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: start with simple tests and add the results to the question.  Things like "ping www.google.com" "nslookup www.google.com" "ipconfig /all" "route print".

Comment: Is there a good reason you're trying a web browser instead of `ping` to diagnose connectivity issues??

Comment: Did Avira Internet Security install a proxy (e.g something called the "Web Protection module"? (In which case internet access should just work, except for browsers which use the proxy which has been removed. In that case restore normal setting (e.g. no proxy) in your browser.

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys but i was like trying everything possible.

no pinging works. 
no proxy present.
no NDIS filter under the network adapter properties available.
no entries present in registry

weid thing is i can open a few pages which are all http but https pages of that same website is not opening. no other http/https pages are opening.

one other PC in network but without avira installed started behaving the same just after i uninstalled avirainternet security from this one.

So, finally i have reinstalled windows but still its behaving the same. :(

Comment: could this be some switch issue . can these two pc be connected through same switch ??

Comment: now there are total 3 PC's which are acting the same once i removed the internet security from one PC .
I think its not a problem with one PC . something went wrong in the network .
Like some filter is applied to the swicht connecting those 3 PC's or something .